# How to get the https version of a Uri in .NET?

Tags: .net-core

If I have a `Uri` ([System.Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-5.0)):

```
http://example.com/directory/default.aspx?para=1&parb=abc#xyz
```

How to get the `https` version of this `Uri`, like this?

```
https://example.com/directory/default.aspx?para=1&parb=abc#xyz
```

Also, how to handle the Uri if it has different port for `http` and `https` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?What do you mean by `https version` or `how to handle ... if it has different port`? `https` is the scheme part of the UIRI and has no versions. The port is either specified explicitly after the domain, eg `example.com:80`) or implied by the scheme. For HTTP, it's 80. For HTTPS, 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UriBuilder for that.

```
        var exampleUrl = "http://example.com";
        var builder = new UriBuilder(exampleUrl); // you can also pass a Uri instead of a string.
        builder.scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
        builder.Port = 123;
```

Or you can also pass the relevant information into the constructor

```
UriBuilder myUri = new UriBuilder("http","www.example.com",123); //scheme, uri, port
myUri.uri; // Here is the new uri
```